# Using Anaconda with zsh on Catalina

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, macos-catalina

The Anaconda installer added this script originally to my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` so I copied it over to `.zshrc` when I switched to `zsh`. I recently read I didn't need to/shouldn't have copied it over since it was meant for `.bash_profile`, but now that macOS is moving to use `zsh` anyway I'd like to know what I should do. Obviously I need to tell `zsh` where Anaconda is but do I need that script or can I just export the Anaconda path like `export PATH=/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`?

Script added by Anaconda installer.

```
export PATH=/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/ty604/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/ty604/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

I also have many duplicate paths in $PATH because of duplicate export commands in various shell files. 
**$ echo $PATH**
`/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:/Users/ty604/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:/Users/ty604/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Users/ty604/flutter/bin`

Files in my system
`.bash_history, .bash_profile, .bashrc, .profile, .zprofile, .zsh_history, .zshrc, .zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh`

Folders in my system
`.bash_sessions, .oh-my-zsh, .zsh`

macOS will be using `zsh` moving forward and we can set `zsh` as the default shell in Catalina which I have done. With Catalina is it ok if I remove all traces of `bash` and `oh-my-zsh` since `zsh` is now the default shell? Also I am using `Hyper Terminal` which means I do not need `oh-my-zsh` any longer right?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `zsh` as your shell (which is up to you, since Catalina still provides bash as well), and need some settings for it, they should go into `.zshrc`, respectivels `.zprofile`. Of course you don't blindly copy everything from `.bashrc` over, because you need to be sure that the code is valid under Zsh too. However, the code snippet you posted, looks safe for me, i.e. it should work under both bash and zsh.

In this case, I suggest (for easier maintenance) to put initialization code common to bash and zsh into a separate file, say `~/.commonrc`, and source this file in `.zshrc` and `.bashrc`. Note also that `.zshrc` is only read if this is an interactive shell. See the section *STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES* in the *zshall* man-page.

Comment: ok well what I would really like to know is since Catalina now defaults to `zsh` is can I actually remove any traces of `bash` since all `PATHs` originate from `.profile -> etc` and not `bash` anyway? I only want to use `zsh` + `Hyper`. I am using `Hyper` instead of `oh-my-zsh` so I should be able to remove all `oh-my-zsh` related files as well? Also what `zsh` related files are absolutely necessary? Do we need both `.zprofile` and `.zshrc`? And do I need that entire `conda` script? Can I not just have a simple `conda` path?

Comment: Also that `conda` script mentions `shell.bash`. So does that mean trouble if I remove bash files? I would have to wait for a conda update that mentions `shell.zsh` instead?

Comment: Did you verify whether there exists a shell.zsh hook? I have never worked with Anaconda, but according to [this](https://medium.com/@msarahan/hello-from-the-anaconda-team-and-thanks-for-writing-this-up-3891e4ea2c0d), it might be worth a try.

Comment: I didn't even know what a hook was until now. I would also like to know if we even need that script so I'll take a look and come back. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted. I found the answer I was looking for via an unrelated Anaconda dev post. She specifically uses `shell.zsh hook`.

Answer (score 0):

Found out via an Anaconda dev post that she was using

`conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/user_name/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.zsh hook 2> /dev/null)"`

Couldn't find `shell.zsh hook` anywhere else so hopefully this will help someone else.

I am proceeding to move all bash files outside of my system since the default macOS zsh shell is now zsh.